# Getting current location of user using Azure maps

Tags: django, azure, geolocation, azure-maps

I'm working on a Django project where I need the current location of the user when the user presses a certain button.
I need to do this with the help of Azure Maps. I have read their [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/tutorial-search-location). Still, I'm unable to find a way to get the user's location.
What I want is when the user presses the button the Azure maps API must return me the user's location.
1. Is it possible to get the user's location using Azure maps?
2. If yes, how can I get started ( any resource/documentation )?

Answer (score 0):

Getting the users location while in a browser can be done using the geolocation API that is built into the browser, there is no need to use any other library, such as Azure Maps. If Azure Maps were to provide such a feature they would simply wrap this built in feature (this is what other mapping platforms do too). Here is some docs: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

Here is a code sample that uses the geolocation API with Azure Maps: https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/#device-sensors

Answer (score 0):

This [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/search/getsearchaddressreverse) is quite helpful. There are several requests you can make, one of them returns the address based on the latitude and longitude.
Here's an example:

> GET https://atlas.microsoft.com/search/address/reverse/{format}?subscription-key={subscription-key}&api-version=1.0&query={query}

Just plug-in the values(format, subscription-key etc.).

format: Desired format of the response. Value can be either json or xml.
subscription-key: Azure Maps subscription key( you will get this through your Azure maps account ).
query: The applicable query specified as a comma separated string composed by latitude followed by longitude e.g. "47.641268,-122.125679".
You can use the above url( with the values plugged in ) to get the required response.

Comment: Hi, could you add some more detail to your answer? For example, what request did you end up using? If someone else was to have the same question, would your answer help them? And while links to documentation can be helpful, links can break so it is preferable to have self-contained answers.

Comment: Updated the answer ;)

Comment: This doesn't find the users location. This provides the address for a know coordinate which you have to already have.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event listener on a custom control like so. How do you add the button to the map? I've neither figured that out yet nor found an example to do so.

```js
//If the user presses the My Location button, use the geolocation API to get the users location and center/zoom the map to that location.
    document.getElementById('myLocationBtn').onclick = setMapToUserLocation;

function setMapToUserLocation() {
    //Request the user's location.
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
        //Convert the geolocation API position into a longitude/latitude position value the map can understand and center the map over it.
        map.setCamera({
            center: [position.coords.longitude, position.coords.latitude],
            zoom: maxClusterZoomLevel + 1
        });
    }, function (error) {
        //If an error occurs when trying to access the users position information, display an error message.
        switch (error.code) {
            case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                alert('User denied the request for Geolocation.');
                break;
            case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                alert('Position information is unavailable.');
                break;
            case error.TIMEOUT:
                alert('The request to get user position timed out.');
                break;
            case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
                alert('An unknown error occurred.');
                break;
        }
    });
}
```

Code sample courtesy of: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/AzureMapsCodeSamples/issues/57